# Multiply multi-dimensional matrix to get new dataframe with new column names

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I created 2 DataFrames with [6,2] and [3,2]. I want to multiple 2 DataFrames to get [6,3] matrix. I am using the loop below but it is giving me a return self._getitem_column(key) error.Below is an example.

```
df1= pd.DataFrame{[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                  [23,24,25,26,27,28]}
df2= pd.DataFrame{[1,2,3], 
                  [12,13,14]}        

for j in range(len(df2)):    
    for i in range(len(df1)):    
       df3 = (df1[i, 2] * df2[j,2])
#expected result
df3= {0  1       2        3
      1  276     299     322
      2  288     312     336
      3  300     325     350
      4  312     338     364
      5  324     351     378
      6  336     364     392}
```

[I am trying to replicate what I did in an excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSwJY.jpg)

Comment: You should not include your data as a picture if you want people to adequately assist you. Take the time to type your input data and expected output when asking a question and you will be much more likely to achieve a result.

Comment: the image i am trying to achieve is hyperlinked to the last line and the code is what i am using.

Comment: I see that, you should type your data into your question so we can easily paste it into a place where we can easily work on your picture. It is not easy for us to work on your data as a picture.

Comment: I hope this is clear now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Much better! Thanks for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to leave it out of dataframes altogether, unless you have the information in dataframes currently (in which case, write back and I'll show you how to do that).

For now, this might be easier:

```
list1 = list(range(23,29)) # note that you have to go one higher to include 28
list2 = list(range(12,15)) # same deal
outputlist = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        outputlist.append(i * j)

import numpy as np
outputlist = np.array(outputlist).reshape(len(df1),len(df2))
import pandas as pd
df3 = pd.DataFrame(outputlist)
```

EDIT: Ok, this might get you where you need to go, then:

```
list3 = []
for j in range(len(df2)):    
    for i in range(len(df1)):    
       list3.append(df1.loc[i+1,0] * df2.loc[j+1,0])
import numpy as np
list3 = np.array(outputlist).reshape(len(df1),len(df2))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list3)
```

EDIT AGAIN: Try this!  Just make sure you replace "thenameofthecolumnindf1" with the actual name of the column in df1 that you're interested in, etc.

```
import numpy as np
list3 = []
for i in df1[thenameofthecolumnindf1]:    
    for j in df2[thenameofthecolumnindf2]:    
       list3.append(i * j)

list3 = np.array(list3).reshape(len(df1),len(df2))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list3)
```

Comment: Yes. I have information in the dataframes. This is an example I could come up with closely related to what I am trying to achieve. Thanks. reshape function may not work as the shape will change based on dataframe output.

Comment: Gotcha, see above (I think this might do it).  I think part of the reason it's having trouble is that the index in your dataframe starts at 1, instead of 0, the way Python usually starts indexing.  In your for loops, the first "i" it's looking at is actually 0, and you don't have a 0 in your dataframes.  Does the fix above work for you?

Comment: df1 and df2 are not lists but they are dataframes with random values in my logic. I am trying to modify your idea to accommodate into my logic. Thanks. This is getting me close.

Comment: Great!  I think that the code under the "Edit" should work for you even though df1 and df2 are dataframes.  Let me know if it does not

Comment: I am getting a Type Error: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the header of the column in df1 and df2 that you want to look at?

Answer (score 0):

The math for this simply won't work. To do matrix multiplication, Number of columns in the first matrix (6) should be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix (2). You're likely getting a key indexing error because of the mismatched row/column value.

You'll have to account for 3 different dimensions in order to properly multiply them, not just 2 as is done above.